# Formula to fill cell if range isn't blank?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I would like to fill a column cell with an "x" if a range further across that row has any text in it.

[Sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KWLZzcS1Prdquw4GGk3Z9Nz31Hic1xyRSAK4ozITKPQ/edit?usp=sharing)
[image: Q52663735 example]

'A' column would fill with "x" if there are any values in it's row from 'C:F' and stay blank if the row (in that range) is blank.

I've tried variations of `=IF =ISBLANK` for this.

`=IF(ISBLANK(C:F),"","x")` still placed an X even if the row was blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ISBLANK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290) works for a single cell but we do have an alternative:

```
=if(countblank(C2:F2)=4,"","x")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to pnuts' contribution, an array-enabled solution could be

```
=ArrayFormula(if(countif(if(C2:F20<>"", row(2:20)), row(2:20)), "x",))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the above

```
=if(LEN(CONCATENATE(A2:F2))>0,"X","")
```

This grabs all inputs across the row, concatenates them together in one string, counts the length of that combined string, and returns a "X" if it's greater than zero.

This has the advantage that it works if you add more headers (if you extend the range).

The disadvantage is that it would also count whitespaces